# when onBindViewHolder called play video and if not stop video in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I need to play video when `onBindViewHolder()` is called and then if the item is scrolled down or top, I need to stop that video. How to do it in `RecyclerView`'s adapter?

Comment: @Midhilaj: Have you tested the solution?

Comment: @aminography i am testing

Answer (score 1):

You can override [`onViewAttachedToWindow(VH holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH)) and [`onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH)) methods in your adapter. Then start and stop the video in their body. As documentation said:

> `onViewAttachedToWindow` is called when a view created by this adapter has been attached to a window.
>
> `onViewDetachedFromWindow` is called when a view created by this adapter has been detached from its window.

## Visual Result:

[image]

Comment: @pskink: Yes dude, when each item goes out of the screen rect, this method is called for it.

Comment: @pskink: I have developed and added its working visual result.

Comment: When you use `onViewRecycled`, it may not called by going the view out of the visible area. Because recycling the view may not be necessary at the moment.

Comment: onViewAttachedToWindow called but onViewDetachedFromWindow is not called

Comment: may be this is the isssue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156630/nestedscrollview-issue-with-recyclerview?noredirect=1#comment95144872_54156630

Comment: I think it should not related to nested scrolling. Please post code of your related classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found some links for you :

- [Implementing video playback in a scrolled list (ListView & RecyclerView)](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429)
- https://github.com/Krupen/AutoplayVideos
- https://ene.im/2017/07/09/toro-101-how-to-1/

You can understand the concept after seeing these links.

For your question I just google that [play pause video in recylcerview android](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=8Uv&channel=fs&ei=vY45XNe8E9HyrAG8mrmIBg&q=play%20pause%20video%20in%20recylcerview%20%20android&oq=play%20pause%20video%20in%20recylcerview%20%20android&gs_l=psy-ab.3...73104.85540..85659...1.0..1.293.3480.0j25j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10.z_gAm_LD5Lw) and I hope next time you will do same things as I do.

**Note:** Everything is not possible to write in comment so I wrote as an answer.

Thank you.